# .after() inserting text instead of html

Tags: jquery

Here's the code:

```
$('.list-wrapper').get(listValInData).after('<div class=\"list-wrapper list-num'+listValInData+' placeholder\"><ul id=\"sortable'+listValInData+'\" class=\"connectedSortable\"><div class=\"list-title\"><select class=\"selectList'+listValInData+' options\"></select></div></ul></div>');
```

Instead of rendering html, I get text. Any idea how to fix this?

Here's the codepen https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/NaxyJK?editors=1010

Comment: (Tried google/jquery docs and there's no easy solution. Hopefully this answer helps others searching with the same question.)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with .get()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `get()` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object. For what you want, you should use `eq()` (`get()` and `eq()` expect an integer as parameter, so also consider casting the value)...

```
$('.list-wrapper').eq(parseInt(listValInData)).after(...
```

I hope it helps